# How to make MySQL select a random winner when using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-order-by, inner-join

```
SELECT * FROM `surveys` INNER JOIN `surveyusers` ON `surveyusers`.`survID` = `surveys`.`survID` WHERE `surveyusers`.`hasWon` = 0 ORDER BY RAND();
UPDATE surveys SET winner = email;
```

This was a school assignment that required us to select and update the survey winner.

I use PHP to manage and show surveys, I want the SQL to pick the winner. PHP sets `survID`

I want to pick a random winner and set the winner coloumn in surveys table to the email in the surveyusers table. But I really have a lot of trouble with it.

Comment: what is your table schema?

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() = trouble

Comment: @DanFromGermany I know, but it was a fast solution.

Comment: You should not do the logic part (pick random winner and assign to something) in MySQL. That's not was MySQL is made for and it's not working out good either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates can take the same syntax as a Select.

You can combine these two queries into one.

```
UPDATE `surveys` `s` SET `s`.`winner` = (
    SELECT email FROM `surveyusers`
    WHERE `surveyusers`.`hasWon` = 0
    AND `survID` = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
) WHERE `survID` = 1;
```

The survID you would have to set from PHP of course.

Comment: MySQL just gives my this error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'surveys' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @LasseNielsen Sorry I forgot that you need to make copies of the table when you update. The query has been updated.

Comment: Either I must be very stupid, or else is my MySQL database version be very old and outdated. #1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY  Is the new error.

Comment: @LasseNielsen You are right, ORDER BY with RAND does not work with UPDATE, the ORDER BY for UPDATE is a bit special. I reverted my answer to my previous approach with a subselect (not as good as joins) but it will work with rand. Also I fixed the previous bug you had.

Answer (score -1):

You can nest a SELECT query within your UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE surveys SET winner = (
    SELECT `surveyusers`.email FROM `surveys` 
    INNER JOIN `surveyusers` ON `surveyusers`.`survID` = `surveys`.`survID` 
    WHERE `surveyusers`.`hasWon` = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) WHERE `survID` = xxx
```

where xxx is the survey to update.